# Is any malevolent entity(like satan/iblis in abrahmic religions)present in Hinduism?

Tags: other-religions, maya

I would like to know if any malevolent entity is present in Hinduism which us equivalent to devil in abrahmic religions.If I remember correctly, once Srila Prabhupada compared Maya to satan/devil and Brahman/Ishvara as abrahmic God.But Maya as devil is pretty abstract.I would like to know if satan-like figure is present in Hinduism.

Comment: Question regarding concept of Satan in Hinduism is already present here with answers. So I am for time being closing your question as Duplicate.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar how is this question duplicate? We are not just talking about evil spirits this question is about satan the prime force against biblical god and who is also a fallen angel.

Comment: In one word, no. An evil variant of the Godhead only exists in dualisitc traditions. It first appeared in the early Persian traditions, was rejected by the Vedas but took form in the Abrahamic traditions. All is Brahman; Love Absolute. If all is Brahman, how can there be an evil polar opposite? Would it not be part of Brahman?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda but what about dualist traditions within Hinduism?